# How to profile an Erlang program in terms of memory usage?

Tags: erlang, profiling

**I would like to further enhance the efficiency of an existing Erlang program. First I would like to identify bottlenecks and then decide on where to further optimize.**

I have tryed `fprof`, but it only gives information on total and average runtime. I would most like to see a log similar to the output of fprof, but in terms of average and total memory usage with respect to functions and processes.

---

For starters it would be enough to profile a single module, that does not spawn processes, only it's functions would be called. This would already help, for I could separate the program to distinct modules for testing.

---

Typical suspicious points are, where bigger lists are being handled.

Here the usage of `++` has been resolved by `lists:reverse([Head|Tail])` like syntax.

I am also considering using ETS tables instead of Lists for cases with more than a few hundred elements.

Thank You in advance!

Comment: I doubt using ets tables over lists will be an advantage in terms of space, no matter how large the list/ets table is (a list only has an overhead of one pointer per element) -- ets tables usually only give you an advantage in time.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Doing some advertising for my own sake: I wrote a little erlang gen_server a while ago, that records and logs system statistics, combined with a little perl script that parses them and outputs pretty charts.

I've found it pretty useful for doing memory watching etc. under load, as it allows you to continuously monitor a detailed view of the memory usage, while for instance testing different things.

The erlang part is fairly non-intrusive, a simple gen_server that you can start from anywhere, you can just put it under your supervision tree. You can configure the poll frequency etc, and it will write statistics to a file in a simple json format.

The perl script then runs over it, and aggregates the logs to draw charts. There are base-classes, and if you know a little perl, you can easily write a class to log and chart any custom parameter you want.

The script can be obtained from: https://github.com/Amadiro/erlang-statistics

Sample chart (Erlang node that leaks atoms): [Sample Chart http://monoc.mo.funpic.de/ram-usage-vs-time.png](http://monoc.mo.funpic.de/ram-usage-vs-time.png)

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: All links are dead, please consider removing or editing the post

Answer (score 4):

The perfect starting point is the Profiling section from the Erlang Efficiency Guide:

http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/profiling.html

Comment: Thank You for the answer, but my problem with the tools mentioned in the Erlang Efficiency Guide is that they all focus on runtime and I need memory usage related information.

Answer (score 3):

@brainiac, I'm posting new url for erlang-statistics repo on github: https://github.com/Amadiro/erlang-statistics (found it by search ;-)).

Comment: Thanks for posting, I changed my display name on github a while ago, and didn't notice that it invalidated all old repository URLs. Oops! In any case, the url https://github.com/Amadiro/erlang-statistics is the official version.

Answer (score 3):

As a more production-ready solution I can recommend collectd erlang client https://github.com/athoune/erlang-collectd if you really need some sort of total memory consumption graphs.

But for more granular memory information you can use `process_info(Pid, [memory])` to get memory information for a specific Pid and shell command `i()` for list of all processes with memory and runtime information.
There is also such utilite as etop.

But there is no such profiler like fprof, but for memory usage.

Refer to http://www.erlang.org/faq/how_do_i.html#id52731 for details.