# Memory Monitoring Tool for Erlang Threads

Tags: erlang, monitoring, pthreads

Anyone know of a decent tool to monitor the **total memory** usage of a program that spawns a lot of threads? I'm really new to developing in Erlang and would appreciate any help!

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If standard tools like top,fprof or similar cannot help you, possibly this other question: [erlang-memory-usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823469/how-to-profile-an-erlang-program-in-terms-of-memory-usage) can be useful to you.

Answer (score 2):

[Erlang - Profiling](http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/profiling.html)